# delete files using firebase cloud functions

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have an application using firestore. The users can upload files to firebase storage. Each file can be referenced by multiple documents in firestore. To manage how many documents that reference each file I use  realtime db records that have a path to the file and a reference counter. To manage the reference counter I have 2 cloud functions:

```
export const onDocumentCreate = functions.firestore
    .document('/collections/{collection}/documents/{document}')
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
        const rtdb = admin.database();
        const document = snapshot.data();

        console.log(`onDocumentCreate() path: /files/${document.fileKey}`);

        // Run a transaction to update the file referencecount
        return rtdb.ref(`/files/${document.fileKey}`).transaction((post: FileDoc) => {
            if (post) {
                post.referenceCount++;
            }
            return post;
        });
    });

export const onDocumentDelete = functions.firestore
.document('/collections/{collection}/documents/{document}')
.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {
    const rtdb = admin.database();
    const document = snapshot.data();

    console.log(`onDocumentDelete() path: /files/${document.fileKey}`);

    // Run a transaction to update the file referencecount
    const rtdbRef = rtdb.ref(`/files/${document.fileKey}`);
    return rtdb.ref(`/files/${document.fileKey}`).transaction(async (post: FileDoc) => {
        if (post) {
            post.referenceCount--;

            if (post.referenceCount <= 0) {
                if (post.referenceCount < 0) console.log('referenceCount < 0');

                await admin.storage().bucket().file(post.path).delete(); // Remove file from storage
                await rtdbRef.remove();                                  // Remove file node from rt db
            }
        }
        return post;
    });
});
```

The realtime record is created by the app with a referenceCount = 0 and reference count is then incremented each time OnDocumentCreate is called. When a document is deleted by the app onDocumentDelete is called and the reference counter is decremented. When referenceCount reaches 0 the file and the  realtime record is deleted.

This works nicely when firestore documents are created and deleted at a reasonable speed. If I however stress it and makes a lot of creates and deletes, the onDocumentDelete starts to timeout. The record in the realtime db is however still deleted correctly, but the files in storage are not deleted.

What is my error here? Are deleting files from storage so slow that I need to handle that in a different way, or have I made an error in my code?

Comment: Add logging to your code and study the output.  Are you absolutely certain you know what's causing the function to time out?

Comment: You shouldn't do long-running work inside of a RTDB transaction -- that will cause it to retry (also I'm pretty sure won't even work since the transaction function has to be synchronous). Instead, delete the file from storage first, then when that completes run the RTDB transaction.